Convert ED25519 private key from hexadecimal encoded string to DER
Using JavaScript and Node.js, how can I reliably convert an ED25519 private key (used on Hedera Testnet) from hexadecimal encoded string format to DER encoded?
Example input value:
6c91776d90126ce548ac1a399cc174383483d54874297d0f8d083aaXXXXXXXX
The output should be something like this:
302e020100300506032b657004220420xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Please may you provide example expected output and your current approach as a text-based [mre]?

Yep, I added the expected output. The answer below works for me.

Create a script: convert.js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import {PrivateKey} from "@hashgraph/sdk";

let hex = process.argv[2];
console.log(hex);

let x = PrivateKey.fromStringED25519(hex);
let der = x.toBytesDer();

let derhex = Buffer.from(der).toString('hex');
console.log(derhex);

Run:
npm i

Set "type": "module" in package.json
Run:
./convert.js

